# Filter scope by categories true underscore

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I need to filter only posts that have within categories, eg desenvolvimento: true.

I tried to use the underscore , but could not get it back me all the posts, needed only the posts that contain this filter.

```
$scope.filter = 'desenvolvimento';
$scope.teste = _.where($scope.posts, 'desenvolvimento');
```

RESOLVED!!! example in JsBin

Follows the JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/turodayaqe/1/edit?html,output

Comment: YOur code is only iterating on the first level, _.each isn't iterating over nested keys, so your "post.tax.categories. desenvolvimento' isn't reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or underscore's [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and just check the existence of the properties chain, and the end result ([demo](https://jsbin.com/ramegayesi/1/edit?html,js,output)):

```
$scope.filter = 'artigos';

$scope.resolve = $scope.posts.filter(function (item) {
        return !!(item.tax && item.tax.categorias && item.tax.categorias[$scope.filter]); // go over the props chain, if anything is missing it will return false
    });
```

Comment: THIS filter function directly any scope, I did not know , very good. Once output , thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case you would need something like:

```
_.each(obj, function (v1, k1) {
  _.each(v1, function(v2){
    if(typeof v2 === "object") {
      _.each(v2, function(v3){
        console.log(v3);
        if(v3 === value) {
          // do something
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

But I'm not quite sure what you want to do.

Comment: What I need is pretty simple, I want to take the object only posts that have the category of "development". I am applying on a filter by category in angular.

Comment: $scope.teste = _.map(_.map($scope.posts, 'tax'), 'categorias');

This partial worked